# How do i input a character without pressing enter on mac?

Tags: c++

So I have this program that tells you the number of characters and vowels in a paragraph.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter your paragraph\nTo finish press 'ESC'\n\n";
    
    //27 Is The ESC Button In ASCII
    char s[500];
    cin.getline(s, 500, 27);
    
    //Vowel and Character counters
    long long vowels = 0, characters = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<500; i++) s[i] = tolower(s[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i<500; i++) {
        if(s[i] == 'a'||s[i] == 'e'||s[i] == 'i'||s[i] == 'o'||s[i] == 'u'||s[i] == 'y')vowels++;
        if(s[i] >= 32 && s[i] <= 126) characters++;
    }
    cout<<"The amount of characters: "<<characters<<"\nThe amount of vowels: "<<vowels<<'\n';
}
```

How do I make it so that when the user presses **ESC**, it immediately does the output **(On Mac)**?

When the user presses **ESC**, it's supposed to print the number of characters and vowels in your paragraph, but when you press **ESC**, you must press enter actually to output.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the program. Terminal buffers and sends input data to the program on Enter. I don't think you want to ask a user to tune Terminal. You can request to press Ctrl+D instead of Esc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key press is part of your assignment, which would be unusual, I recommend you simply structure to a very common standard:

- paragraphs end with two newlines

Read characters until the user presses a newline followed immediately by another newline. Your prompt then becomes a very simple:

```
std::cout << "Type your paragraph. Press 'Enter' twice to finish:\n\n";
```

Otherwise you should follow the linked posts about manipulating “raw” vs “cooked” input on Linux systems.